# Did Job ever realize, while he was alive, that it was God who allowed Satan to trouble him, as referred in Job 1:12

Tags: job

I want to know, if Job found out the root cause of his suffering when he was alive on this earth. Did Job ever come to know what happened behind the scenes in the spiritual realm when he was alive.

Job 1:12-
And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold, all that he hath is in thy power; only upon himself put not forth thine hand. So Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord.

Comment: The short answer is - we do not know because we are not told.

Answer (score 1):

Job had extreme faith in Jehovah God. Job knew that Jehovah wasn't the cause of his problems. That is one of the major key elements.

Job didn't need to know whether God allowed satan to test him or not. And because Job stayed faithful and loyal to Jehovah, he was blessed with more that what he had before Satan took everything away from him. The moral of the story is knowing that Jehovah is not the source of our problems.

The source of our problems start with us not being perfect and not being strong, faithful, loyal enough to Jehovah God to resist the temptations that Satan and his demons challenge us with.

Answer (score 1):

The answer if probably no. Job was not privy to the discussion between God and Satan in the prologue. He insists consistently that it is God who is punishing him. Job nowhere mentions Satan. So he insists in Ch. 19:

```
 God has put me in the wrong,
    and closed his net about me.
Behold, I cry out, ‘Violence!’ but I am not answered;
    I call aloud, but there is no justice.
He has walled up my way, so that I cannot pass,
    and he has set darkness upon my paths.
He has stripped from me my glory,
    and taken the crown from my head.
He breaks me down on every side, and I am gone,
    and my hope has he pulled up like a tree.
He has kindled his wrath against me,
    and counts me as his adversary.
His troops come on together;
    they have cast up siegeworks against me,
    and encamp round about my tent...
 Have pity on me, have pity on me, O you my friends,
    for the hand of God has touched me!
 Why do you, like God, pursue me?
```

God never mentions Satan in his dialogues it Job.  Indeed God takes responsibility for Job's fate, even saying to Job's detractor Eliphaz, who insisted that Job must have sinned to deserve his suffering:

> My wrath is kindled against you and against your two friends; for you
> have not spoken of me what is right, as my servant Job has.

**Satan disappears after the prologue. Job never mentions him, and God does not refer to Satan's activities.  Thus, the text is fairly clear: neither the narrator nor the words of Job suggest that Job was aware of Satan's role in the drama.**

Answer (score 0):

One of the lessons of the Book of Job for us is trusting God regardless. Job never learned the interactions between God and Satan in heaven. In our lives also, often we have no idea what is happening in God's plan for us. But we still trust in God's sovereignty and believe that in all things God works for the good of those who love him, who have been called according to his purpose.

God is the potter and we are the clay. He does not need to explain everything to us. Otherwise, what is the point of faith?

Answer (score 0):

The situation wasn't just a test for Job, but it was also a look into satan's character.

What would motivate one to call for the of death somebody's loved ones and for the destruction of one's property?

Obviously, satan is motivated by hatred, jealousy, lust, nescience, folly, and whatever other foul stimuli there are.

Which leads us to the question, would satan have stopped before killing Job if God hadn't forbidden it.

The answer is a definite, no!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/49893)

Comment: @ Robert Piimauna - What was said about Satan  in ypur answer is quite true, however this does not deal with the posted question about "Job's understanding" of his situation. It's best to stick to the question's intent. Also, it is not best to add another question in the Answer section.  That should be posted elsewhere.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!